# SQLITE, access the matched expression of REGEXP operator

Tags: regex, database, sqlite

How is it possible to capture the expression matched with REGEXP operator in sqlite?As an example if we have a query like: `select title from foo where title REGEXP '(\d\d)ab?cd'`, how can we extract the exact expression that has matched the REGEXP operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REGEXP is not defined by SQLite, but rather it's a placeholder for a user-defined function. Usually this is provided by [sqlite3-pcre](https://github.com/ralight/sqlite3-pcre) which only returns true or false.

You can write your own function to change that, either in C or in the language of your choice.  Here's an example of writing your own [REGEXP in Perl](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/sqlite/add_regexen.html).  Altering [pcre.c](https://github.com/ralight/sqlite3-pcre/blob/master/pcre.c) to return, for example, the first match isn't that difficult.  Most of the code is concerned with caching.  Instead of passing true or false, you'd pass in the matched substring from [`pcre_exec`](http://pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre_exec.html) to [`sqlite3_result_text`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/result_blob.html).

I'd suggest writing a new function and leaving REGEXP alone.

Answer (score 0):

You need one or two [sqlite extensions](https://sqlite.org/loadext.html).

If you want the whole matching string, I've had a go at an
extension implementing MATCH - on [github](https://github.com/njamescouk/matchExtension) - which would enable the following query:

```
select title MATCH '(\d\d)ab?cd' from foo;
```

This would return the likes of '12acd', '23abcd' etc.
However, it looks like you just want the leading digits? In
that case my best offer is:

```
select title MATCH '\d\d' from foo where title REGEXP '\d\dab?cd';
```

Which would select the relevant lines and extract things like '12', '23' etc.

Source code for the REGEXP extension is at [regexp.c](https://www.sqlite.org/src/file?name=ext/misc/regexp.c&ci=trunk)

The catch is that you have to compile these yourself with gcc and/or
g++, which may involve downloads and learning curves...